# Migrating from TFS to GITHUB

Tags: github, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

We have decided to migrate to GITHUB from TFS, we use Microsoft Test Manager to execute and manage our test cases. Can i execute my tests on MTM using GITHUB or we have to keep our TFS in order to execute our tests using MTM.

Answer (score 5):

Test Manager needs a TFS server to store its test cases. You cannot store Test Manager test cases in GitHub.

If git is important to you, you might also evaluate [Visual Studio Online](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) which supports Git and Test Manager. It's not the same as GitHub (no support for pull requests at the moment for example).

Answer (score 0):

For those considering Microsoft's Team Foundation Server (TFS) or GitHub, the following page from the Microsoft News Center may be of interest. (The first four paragraphs of text from this page are listed below this link.)

**[Microsoft to acquire GitHub for $7.5 billion](https://news.microsoft.com/2018/06/04/microsoft-to-acquire-github-for-7-5-billion/)**

REDMOND, Wash. — June 4, 2018 — Microsoft Corp. on Monday announced it has reached an agreement to acquire GitHub, the world’s leading software development platform where more than 28 million developers learn, share and collaborate to create the future. Together, the two companies will empower developers to achieve more at every stage of the development lifecycle, accelerate enterprise use of GitHub, and bring Microsoft’s developer tools and services to new audiences.

“Microsoft is a developer-first company, and by joining forces with GitHub we strengthen our commitment to developer freedom, openness and innovation,” said Satya Nadella, CEO, Microsoft. “We recognize the community responsibility we take on with this agreement and will do our best work to empower every developer to build, innovate and solve the world’s most pressing challenges.”

Under the terms of the agreement, Microsoft will acquire GitHub for $7.5 billion in Microsoft stock. Subject to customary closing conditions and completion of regulatory review, the acquisition is expected to close by the end of the calendar year.

GitHub will retain its developer-first ethos and will operate independently to provide an open platform for all developers in all industries. Developers will continue to be able to use the programming languages, tools and operating systems of their choice for their projects — and will still be able to deploy their code to any operating system, any cloud and any device.